# Plot three-variable line chart

Tags: r, line-plot

I need to plot a line chart that contains 2 lines, as per the `dataset` below:

[image]

I need each line of the chart to match the Technique. The values of X and Y are Release and Added respectively. The graph I need to generate is similar to the one in the figure below:

[image]

To plot the first line, I tried:

```
plot(IrisChangeModules[IrisChangeModules$Technique=="aop"]$Added, IrisChangeModules[IrisChangeModules$Technique=="aop"]$Release, type = "l")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ggplot` (not a `base r` solution though), one way of getting your desired output can be:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Release, y=Added, group=Technique)) + geom_line(aes(linetype = Technique, color=Technique)) + geom_point(aes(color = Technique)) + theme_bw()
```

The output given your dummy data looks:
[image: sample_output]

You can play with the different parameters of `ggplot` to position the legend and other aspects of the plot.

UPDATE:

1. Remove `ylab("Added Modules") + scale_color_discrete(name = "SPL Techniques")` from your script and save the output on a variable as follows:

   ```
   x <- ggplot(IrisChangeModules, aes(x=Release, y=Added, group=Technique))  + geom_line(aes(linetype = Technique, color=Technique)) + geom_point(aes(color = Technique)) + theme_bw()
   ```
2. Then overlay your modified label and new legend title as:

   ```
   x+ labs(y = "Added Modules") + scale_fill_discrete(name = "SPL Techniques")
   ```

That'll give you what you want.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but maybe you can help me. I used the library you indicated but I'm having a problem with the graphic caption when I add another title because the caption gets duplicated. Look at this result: http://prntscr.com/olqutc. I tried using labs and scale_color_discrete. I have tried: `ggplot(IrisChangeModules, aes(x=Release, y=Added, group=Technique)) + ylab("Added Modules") + scale_color_discrete(name = "SPL Techniques") + geom_line(aes(linetype = Technique, color=Technique)) + geom_point(aes(color = Technique)) + theme_bw()`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create an ordered release int
`IrisChangeModules$release_n = 1:nrow(IrisChangeModules)`

Now create a blank plot, `type="n"` means nothing is actually plotted.
`plot(Added~release_n,data=IrisChangeModules,type="n",xaxt = "n")`

Create axis labels with the original variable ( you may need to update the `at` if you have more than 4 releases).
`axis(1,at=1:4,labels=IrisChangeModules$Release)`

Add lines are required

```
lines(Added~release_n,data=IrisChangeModules[IrisChangeModules$tech=="dop",],type='l',col="green")
lines(Added~release_n,data=IrisChangeModules[IrisChangeModules$tech=="aop",],type='l',col="red")
```

Add a legend, make sure you are updating if you add more lines

```
legend(1,90, 
       legend=c("dop", "aop"),
       col=c("green", "red"), 
       lty=1, 
       cex=0.8)
```